# Q-learning with linear function approximation

Tags: algorithm, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, function-approximation

I would like to get some helpful instructions about how to use the Q-learning algorithm with function approximation. For the basic Q-learning algorithm I have found examples and I think I did understand it. In case of using function approximation I get into trouble. Can somebody give me an explanation through a short example how it works?

What I know:

1. Istead of using matrix for Q-values we use features and parameters.
2. Make approximation with the linear combination of feauters and parameters.
3. Update the parameters.

I have checked this paper: [Q-learning with function approximation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.7833&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

But I cant find any useful tutorial how to use it.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my view, [this](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node85.html) is one of the best references to start with. It is well written with several pseudo-code examples. In your case, you can simplify the algorithms by ignoring eligibility traces.

Also, to my experience and depending on your use case, Q-Learning might not work very well (sometimes it needs huge amounts of experience data). You can try Fitted-Q value for example, which is a batch algorithm.

Comment: The link you have attached is no longer working

Comment: You are right, here is the new link: http://incompleteideas.net/book/ebook/node85.html